# Read a double number from stdin, with C read()

Tags: c, floating-point

According to the Linux [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read),

```
#include <unistd.h>
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

attempts to read up to count bytes from file descriptor fd into the buffer starting at buf.

I am writing a C program that uses "read" (instead of scanf) to read a double from stdin. Below is what I get. I typed inputs such as 42.0, 47.9, etc from the console. It turns out that the program produces random outputs. Can anyone help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    double x;
    read(0, &x, sizeof(x));
    printf ("Results = %g\n", x);
}
```

Comment: Please also add how you run this code (specifically : what do you place on `stdin` ? do you simply type or do you redirect from a file in which a `double` was previously written with `write` ?).

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I typed the inputs from  the console. See my edits.

Answer (score 1):

Input on standard input (please use `STDIN_FILENO` instead of the "magic number" `0`) is usually ***text***.

You attempt to read the input as a raw binary representation of the value.

Unless you *know* that the input will be in raw binary form (for example from redirection of a binary file or from a pipe where the other end is writing raw binary data) I suggest you read into a character buffer, make sure the buffer is null-terminated (you have to do it yourself, the position is what `read` return if successful), and use e.g. `sscanf` or [`strtod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) to convert the string.

Comment: The sentence “You attempt to read the input as a raw binary representation of the value” is confusing and may be hard for a learner to interpret. First, it presumes to assert something about the OP’s intent regarding what they are attempting. It is really trying to be a sentence about how the `read` routine behaves, and it ought to be phrased that way, not as an assertion about what the OP is doing. That phrasing may leave them confused and not even understand the sentence is about the `read` call.

Comment: Second, there is no such thing as a “raw binary representation” of a floating-point value. Floating-point necessarily has some form of encoding other than binary. It must—it has a sign, a significand, and an exponent, so its representation must be partitioned into fields, at least; it cannot be represented as a binary numeral. More than that, those fields are not pure binary even individually. `read` will read bytes without interpreting them into an object. It reads the bytes that represent an object.

Comment: Normally, binary representation of floating point data is universally following the IEEE-752 format for floating point  numbers.  This is normally the format used to `write(2)` the data stored in a floating point variable (with the bytes in _big endian_ or _little endian_ order --if can be so called for a floating point number-- depending on the architecture) this is the raw binary representation I thing that Some programmer dude means.

Comment: @SomeProgrammerDude, using `0` for stdin is a legacy from ancient unix, and still there's a lot of code that uses it.  Unfortunately, `STDIN_FILENO` is a recommendation of POSIX, that is only followed by POSIX. Neither OS/F, SYSVID, nor any original UNIX(tm) follows it, I'm afraid, and you'll get even code that uses the macro at some places, and the integer value in others.  I'm afraid that this is a dead cause.... sincerely.  Please, don't flame me for this comment, that is only a comment.  Same happens to `EXIT_SUCCESS`, `EXIT_FAILURE` and many of the constants defined by posix.

Comment: @EricPostpischil comments are not meant for answers. If you've got a better answer then please do write one.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: My comments do not contain an answer. They contain comments on how to improve this answer.

Answer (score 1):

As the manual says, *attempts to read up to count bytes from file descriptor fd* and that means for a `double` for example to read `sizeof (double)` bytes with the internal format representation of a `double` value.  As it says it reads bytes, those bytes can be generated by a corresponding `write(2)` of a `double` value, but are only understandable by the machine, so entering `24.2` is not valid, as that is a string representation of a number in ascii decimal form.

There's a standard binary representation for internal use on extended use, described in the IEEE-752 standard.  It describes internal binary format representations for `float`, `double` and *extended long doubles* (128bit representation of a floating point number, normally not used in current architectures, but only a small set)  If you know it, probably you can produce the exact representation needed to be able to input correctly a specific number.  You should read that document in order to understand why the sequence of chars `2`, `4`, `.`, `2`, that form the string `24.2` is not the same as the internal binary representation of that number, which is what is written by `write(2)`.

Try to `write(2)` that first, with:

```
double number = 3.1415926535897932;
write(1, &number, sizeof number);
```

and see what happens in your output.  Next try to filter up with a hex reader, as in

```
$ new_program | hd
```

and you'll see the exact values of the bytes that pi produces.  Then, try to feed that to your original program, as in

```
$ new_program | your_original_program
```

and print them again with

```
read(0, &my_double, sizeof my_double);
printf("%g", my_double);
```

you'll see that what was read is what you wrote, but the binary representation of a `double` value is, in general, misunderstandable for humans (well, there's people so used to binary that understand hex dumps up to this level, but I'm not one of them)